# Sometimes getting error while choosing Credit/Debit option using Paypal

Tags: laravel, paypal

I have a Laravel website which is using PayPal Express Checkout as a payment method.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TCUR.png)
If I click the Debit or Credit Card option sometimes its showing the below error message.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s34la.jpg)

We have tried with different browsers and different devices also. We are not getting this problem all the time. We tried clear cache and cookies also. But no luck. We send the above screenshot to Paypal also they are telling like from their side everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Does the error occur before or after entering card details? That is the normal error message for declines. It is the only error message that will ever show, and expected behavior.

Comment: It will show after entering the card details. If we retry to pay again after sometime also sometime this error come again.

Comment: That is normal behavior then, your payment was declined.

Comment: Our customers are frustrated, they are not ready to try again so we are losing the business. Any other solution is there?

Comment: A solution to a declined payment? Uhm, they could try paying with a different credit card. Maybe that won't decline. You can ask PayPal to research some specific declines, but declines are declines.